# sql case statement update based on other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update a table (table1) based on the values of one or more fields in another table (table2).  I believe this should be a case statement but I'm unsure how to incorporate a case statement and an update clause based on another table in one statement.  Here's what I have so far which I know does not work:

```
update table1 i, table2 s 
set i.sales = 'F'
where s.payment = 'Y'
and i.order_no = s.order_no;
```

I know how to do a select based on two tables but that's not very helpful since I don't want to create a new database object - I just want to update an existing object (table1):

```
create or replace view merge as
select
i.order_no
, case when s.payment = 'Y'
then 'F'
end as sales
from table1 i, table2 s
where i.order_no = s.order_no;
```

And I know how to update WITHIN a case statement:

```
UPDATE  table1
SET     sales = (
                 SELECT  CASE 
                            WHEN  foo = 'X'  
                            THEN  'F'
                            ELSE  null
                           END     
                 FROM table1
                )
;
```

I considered a where clause instead of a case statement but it ends up selecting EVERY record and the 2nd table definitely has different values in the payment field:

```
update t1
set sales = 'F'
where exists (select table2.payment
          from table2
          where table2.order_no = table1.order_no
          and table2.payment = 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
update table1 i
   set i.sales = (select case when x.payment = 'Y'
                              then 'F'
                              else i.sales end
                    from table2 x
                   where x.order_no = i.order_no);
```

Comment: When I try this, I get ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Table1 has many columns, the relevant ones being order_no and sales.  Table2 has many columns, the relevant ones being order_no and payment.

Comment: Is the relation between then (table1 and table2) 1-N ? Because in order to this work you have to have a unity between then. This erros states that there is more than one registry on table2 related with one registry on table1. So if the relation 1-N you have to define conditions to each registry on table1 to be related with one on table2

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an oracle running right now (so I cannot check the syntax propertly), but I think you can try something like this:

```
update table1 i
set i.sales = 'F'
where i.order_no IN (select s.order_no from table2 s where s.payment = 'Y')
```

Hope it helps!